# Probability - Am I understanding the problem correctly (Part II)?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

**The problem**

It is given that a certain type of battery has a mean shelf life of $30$ months with a standard deviation of $3$ months.

For a randomly selected battery let  denote the lifetime of the battery. Assuming a normal distribution:
$$X\sim\mathcal{N}(30,9).$$

The question asks to estimate how long $90\%$ of batteries are expected to last.

---

**The solution(?)**

The probability that a randomly selected battery has a lifetime of $\approx2.18$ years can be evaluated as
$$p=\mathbb P(X>2.18)=\mathbb P(Z>-1.28)=0.9$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

I'm uncertain as to why (or why not) $2.18$ years is the estimate of how long $90\%$ of batteries are expected to last.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use your words carefully to interpret the result. Use the calculation by @DavidQuinn, you may say that 90% batteries are expected to last for more than 26.16 hours. You may go the other direction: 90% batteries are expected to last for less than 33.84 hours.

Comment: There are two issues (a) do you want 10th or 90th percentile, (b) converting between months and years. // If $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=30,\sigma=3)$ in months, then $P(X > 2.18yr) = 1-P(X \le 2.18yr)$ can be evaluated in R (where `pnorm` is a CDF) using R code `1-pnorm(2.18*12, 30, 3)`, which returns $ 0.8997274\approx 0.9.$ You can get a useful approximation by standardizing and using printed tables of standard normal dist'n. Is that what you want? // Also, using the normal quantile function (inverse CDF) R code; `qnorm(.1, 30/12, 3/12)` returns $2.179612.$

Answer (score 1):

Using $$z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma},$$
and $$\Phi^{-1}(0.1)=-1.28155...$$
You can get the value of $X$ (in months) from $$\frac{X-30}{3}=-1.28155...$$

Comment: (+1) But might be best to mention units are years--since problem is originally stated in months.

Comment: @BruceET In my answer $X$ will be calculated in months since the mean and sd are given in months, then converted to years if required.